# GITHUB Page is not showing up on website?

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I have created a repository on my github by following the documentation by .github.io/projectName but even still I am getting error 404 any solution ?

Link for my github repo - https://github.com/vivanks/vivanks.github.io-hackoffproject

Link which should work to host that website - https://vivanks.github.io/hackoffproject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is build via `http://username.github.io/repository` so if you have a repository called `HelloWorld` and your username is `OldJenkins654`you can access your repository via `OldJenkins654.github.io/HelloWorld`

Your username is `vivanks` and your repository name is `vivanks.github.io-hackoffproject` so the link is:

```
vivanks.github.io/vivanks.github.io-hackoffproject
```

I guess you want the link to be `vivanks.github.io/hackoffproject`, you can do this by renaming your repository to `hackoffproject`, you don't need to include the github.io url in your repository name :)

(Cool Design by the way I really like it)

Comment: Yeah this was one thing but the main problem was which WebD pointed out add that to your answer so i will mark it so it helps other

Comment: OK :) You can only use github.io for static sites by the way, so your login and register field can't work under github.io, only prototyping

Comment: it's for prototype only

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you enabled Github Pages?
[image]
If not, go to settings => scroll down to Github Pages

Comment: Yeah this is what was disabled thaks.

Comment: yeah after 4 mins

Answer (score 0):

Your repo name does not need to be the full url also. Change that to `hackoffproject`. Your url should then become https://vivanks.github.io/hackoffproject